# getting slices of different size from a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a sample out of a dataset with random size, what I'm trying to do is:

```
# first I'm defining the frequency for each sample size.

population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
weights = [0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]

# with that done, I want to select 10 chunks of data. So I do: 

for _ in range(5):
    n = int(choices(population, weights)[0])
    batch_sizes.append(n)

# where the output looks like: 

batch_sizes = [3, 4, 4, 5, 2]

# data is something like this: 

data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 1000001, 1000002, 1000003]

# What I want is, using the batch_sizes presented above:

[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]  

# and so on.
```

My problem is, how do iterate over data getting a different sample size?

I already tried:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)-batch_size+1, batch_size):
    batch = data[i:i+batch_size]
    print('Batch: ', batch)
```

but that was not successful since I'm not being able to iterate over batch_size as well.

Comment: What should happen after you reach the last item in `batch_sizes`? Do you start over?

Comment: nope, I should have 5 batches from data with the sizes presented in the parameter `batch_sizes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
start = 0
for n in batch_sizes:
    # print for the demo, you can also add to a list
    print(data[start:start+stop])
    start += stop
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
i = 0
for batch_size in batch_sizes:
    batch = data[i:i+batch_size]
    i += batch_size
    print('Batch: ', batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this "*one-line*" assignment:

```
data =[v for v in range(20)]

batch_sizes = [3, 4, 4, 5, 2]

result=[data[sum(batch_sizes[:i]):sum(batch_sizes[:i])+batch_sizes[i]] for i in range(len(batch_sizes))]

print(result)
```

**result**:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17]]
```

Comment: The drawback is that you repeatedly compute the sum of the indices, which has a quadratic behavior (very slow for large inputs).